# SSL certificate configuration in Hashicorp Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have recently started using Vault for storing my api keys and secrets. I am trying to configure it to use HTTPS using ssl certificates and I believe I have done all the steps.

But when i try to launch the url from browser I get a pop-up asking for selecting a certificate. (Image attached). I don't know what is wrong here. When i click Cancel it works fine and loads the page correctly but I shouldn't get getting that pop-up.

My vault config -

```
storage "file" {
  path = "/vault/store/data"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address     = "vault.systems:8200"
  tls_disable = 0
  tls_cert_file = "/app/vault/cert/vault.systems.cer"
  tls_key_file = "/app/vault/cert/vault.systems.key"
}

api_addr = "https://vault.systems:8200"

ui = true
```

Also I have placed the root certificate under `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` and updated the ca-trust.

Everything works fine as below is the response from the curl -

```
user@vault-server-1$ curl -XGET https://vault.systems:8200/v1/sys/health
{"initialized":true,"sealed":true,"standby":true,"performance_standby":false,"replication_performance_mode":"unknown","replication_dr_mode":"unknown","server_time_utc":1604577030,"version":"1.5.3"}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled the certificate authentication method?

Comment: @lxop hi what is that and how to enable that? ```tls_disable``` is set to true so that should use the certificate and when in click on cancel my UI loads just fine. It's just that pop-up is annoying.

Comment: The browser is prompting you for a certificate because your Vault has told the browser that it accepts client certificates. That might be the case if you have enabled the certificate auth method. If you haven't, then I don't know why you are getting the prompt, sorry

Answer (score 3):

Fixing this issue involves making a tweak to your TCP listener's config stanza.  For the TCP listener, Vault includes a parameter called [tls_disable_client_certs](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/listener/tcp#tls_disable_client_certs) which allows you to toggle this functionality.  By default, the value of this parameter is `false` and Vault will request client certificates when available.

To disable this behavior, simply update the TCP listener stanza in your Vault configuration file to include the following line.

```
tls_disable_client_certs = "true"
```

Below is an example of how this would look in a Vault configuration file.

```bash
...  
listener "tcp" {  
  address = "0.0.0.0:8200"  
  tls_cert_file = "/opt/vault/tls/vault-cert.crt"  
  tls_key_file = "/opt/vault/tls/vault-key.key"  
  tls_client_ca_file = "/opt/vault/tls/vault-ca.crt"  
  tls_disable_client_certs = "true"  
}  
...
```

If you'd like to read more, I wrote a [knowledge base article](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/5714330338323-Disable-Prompt-for-Client-Certificate-When-Loading-UI) detailing how to handle this.

Comment: This fixed my issue adding both those settings - `tls_disable_client_certs`  and `tls_client_ca_file`

Answer (score -2):

To disable the client certificate verification, use:

```
tls_disable_client_certs = true
```

Or, the following check can be used to bypass the popup:

```
tls_require_and_verify_client_cert = false
```